# Font of a webpage using custom font to trick scraper

Tags: css, python-3.x, fonts, web-scraping, artificial-intelligence

A website I am attempting to scrape information off has decided to use a custom font that means all information in the code is a jumble of letters. For example: "aEfrg9" could look like "Booked" when under the use of the font. How could I scrape such a webpage?

My thoughts:

1. Download font from page
2. Somehow translate information I'm looking for into the code message font, eg. I want to find "guitar" in the webpage so my program translates it to "hGke8j" using the font file downloaded.

How would I achieve step 2?

I am using Python 3.X

Comment: I think you'll have to share the page you are trying to crawl.

Comment: Maybe they don't want the page scraped?

Comment: @NathanielFlick Not helpful

Comment: @Kermit It would be helpful if you posted a url as user eLRull suggests. A similar technique to hide email addresses is called obfuscation. Hard to tell until we can see the actual code you're trying to scrape. Further, what you are trying to do could be seen as unethical in certain situations, so tread with caution.